# limit the number of post though a category with jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to filter some post with jekyll.
I want to output all post with category: news.

It works fine when i do:

```
  {% for post in site.posts   %}
    {% if post.category[0] == "news" %}
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

but i'd like to limit the output to this filter to a number of posts.
If I apply a `limit: 5` to my `for` loop it doesn't work as Jekyll applies the limit to the total number of posts.

Is it in anyway possible to apply a limit to an already filtered list of posts, something like:

```
  {% for post in site.posts   %}
    {% if post.category[0] == "news" limit:5 %}
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

I can get the list of categories with `site.categories` and list them

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <p>test: {{ category[0] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But i can't seem to be able to narrow to a single category.
I'm trying to do something like:

```
for post in site.categories.news limit:5
  //do something
endfor
```

or

```
for post in site.categories['news'] limit:5
  //do something
endfor
```

but to no avail. Is it possible to filter a category this way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I manage to sort it out.

I couldn't access the filtered list of post through `site.categories.news`
I've added a `tag: news` on all the news page after looking through the jekyll bottstrap documentation.

I can now filter and limit the output of post with:

```
  {% for post in site.tags.news limit:2  %}
    //do something
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. But you should consider marking it as the accepted answer. There's nothing wrong in that :)

Comment: This syntax threw me off. I was expecting it to be `{% for post in site.tags.news | limit: 2 %}`

Answer (score 5):

My code just works. Looks like they fixed it somewhere since 2012.

```
{% for post in site.categories.company limit: 1 %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```